# PDO return lastInsertId() as Zero (0), i didn't understand?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code ? PDO return always the last inserted `id` as 0, I tried everything.!

```
$this->db()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO inbox (sender,recever) VALUES ('1','2')";
$this->db()->exec($sql);        
$project_id =$this->db()->lastInsertId();
```

The `sql` code table :

```
CREATE TABLE inbox(
id int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
sender int,
recever int
);
```

Comment: Did the `exec` succeed? Was that row successfully added?

Comment: Yes the row successfully added, but return zero, i try, with commit and transaction or prepare execute or exec but nothing just zero 0,

Comment: Is it possible that you're using a connection pool and the `lastInsertId()` call happens on a different connection?

Comment: Improved the Question understand-ability in title and contents as well as removed the spaces before the codes in PDO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
//set persistent connection
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->use‌​r,$this->pass,array(‌​PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE));    
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO inbox (sender,recever) VALUES ('1','2')");
$stmt->execute();
$id = $db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Although it is better to use prepared statements since you have more control, not sure that actually fixes anything here.

Comment: yeah i have try but same thing i use the jquery ajax for calling links and insert , but i don-t know maybe the connection is open in another case.

Comment: Try persistent PDO connection: PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE

Comment: Yes it work now, I had never thought of this> thank you i inserted the PERSISTENT on this code  **   $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname",$this->user,$this->pass,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE));
 **

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your `db()` method which creates a new connection every time it is called.

Instead of such method, use a property. Assign your PDO instance to `$this->db` property and then use it whenever you need a PDO connection.

While your current implementation is just terrible, and workaround you have been offered in the other answer is not guaranteed to work. Let alone it shouldn't be used in the first place.